# Integration $\int_0^t x^{5n-1}\ e^{-x/a}\ \mathrm dx$ without Gamma function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

How to integrate this function without using the gamma function?

$$\int_0^t x^{5n-1}\ e^{-x/a}\ \mathrm dx$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a=1/s$ and $5n-1=k$ so the integral looks more familiar:

$$
\int_0^t x^k e^{-sx}dx
$$

Now, I feel like I should integrate to infinity, so note that:
$$
\int_0^t x^k e^{-sx}dx = \int_0^\infty x^k e^{-sx}dx -\int_t^\infty x^k e^{-sx}dx
$$

The first integral is a well-known [Laplace Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform)
 case:
$$
\int_0^\infty x^k e^{-sx}dx = \frac{k!}{s^k}
$$

Now, I'd like to transform the second integral to start from $0$ as well, so I'll make the following change of variables:

$$
u = x-t \iff x = u+t
$$
Such that:
$$
\int_t^\infty x^k e^{-sx}dx = \int_0^\infty (u+t)^k e^{-su -st}du =e^{-st} \int_0^\infty (u+t)^k e^{-su}du
$$

Using binomial expansion:
$$
\int_t^\infty x^k e^{-sx}dx =e^{-st} \int_0^\infty (u+t)^k e^{-su}du = e^{-st}\int_0^\infty \sum _{j=0}^k u^{k-j}t^j \binom{j}{k} e^{-su}du 
$$
Thus:
$$
\int_t^\infty x^k e^{-sx}dx =  e^{-st}\sum _{j=0}^k \frac{(k-j)!}{s^{k-j}}t^j \binom{j}{k}
$$
Finally:
$$
\int_0^t x^k e^{-sx}dx = \frac{k!}{s^k} - e^{-st}\sum _{j=0}^k \frac{(k-j)!}{s^{k-j}}t^j \binom{j}{k}
$$

Now you need to replace back $a$ and $n$.

Comment: Thank you for this clear answer!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean $\int_0^x t^{2n-1}e^{-t/a}dt$, use *integration by parts*, 2n-1 times.  For the first step, let $u= t^{2n-1}$, $dv= e^{-t/a}dt$.  Then $du= (2n-1)t^{2n-2}dt$ and $v= -ae^{-t/a}$ so the integral becomes $\left[-at^{2n-1}e^{-t/a}\right]_0^x- a\int_0^x t^{2n-2}e^{-t/a}dt= -ax^{2n-1}e^{-x/a}- a\int_0^x t^{2n-2}e^{-t/a}dt$.  Repeat until the power of t in the integral is reduced to 0.

Comment: Thanks! It's what I do but i don't know how to write $$ -ae^{(-t/a)}t^{(5n-1)} + ae^{(-t/a)}t^{(5n-2)} (5n-1) - ae^{(-t/a)}t^{(5n-3)} (5n-1)(5n-2) + ...$$ as a sum.

Comment: Are you required to write it in "closed form"?